# how do I mock Identity.UserManager<TUser>.GetUserName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, moq, xunit

I am trying to do Unit Testing for methods which checks if the user is logged in. I am using xunit and moq and I am able to create a mock user object with the correct claims and everything but it(_userManager.GetUserName(User);) returns null in the controller.

I am not able to pass the mock user as a valid user in the controller method "GetUserName".

```
public virtual string GetUserName(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal);
/// <summary>
/// Returns the User ID claim value if present otherwise returns null.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="principal">The <see cref="T:System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal" /> instance.</param>
/// <returns>The User ID claim value, or null if the claim is not present.</returns>
/// <remarks>The User ID claim is identified by <see cref="F:System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier" />.</remarks>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Controller:
When I debug the test, the line var user returns null..

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] Product productModel)
{
    var user = _userManager.GetUserName(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, value = "Please Log in to Continue." });
    }
    if (productModel.Id == Guid.Empty)
    {               
        try
        {
            productModel.CreatedBy = user;
            productModel.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            await _unitOfWork.ProductRepo.AddProductAsync(productModel);
            await _unitOfWork.Complete();

            return Json(new {id=productModel.Id, success = true, value = "Successfully Added." });
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             _logging.Invoke(ex, "Failed.");
             return Json(new {success = false, value = "Failed."});
         }                
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Post_ValidUser_EmptyId_Add_ReturnSuccess()
{
    var user = GetUser();

    var userManager = _context.UserManager(user.Id, out _httpContext);

    var controller = new ProductsController(_mockUnitOfWork.Object, userManager, null, null);
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = _httpContext;

    var productModel = new Product()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = "Test",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    var result = await controller.Post(productModel);
    Assert.IsType<JsonResult>(result);

    var responseString = result as JsonResult;
    Assert.NotNull(responseString);
    var success = responseString.Value.GetType().GetProperty("success")?.GetValue(responseString.Value);
    Assert.Equal(true, success);
}
```

InitHttpContext:

```
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager(string userId, out HttpContext httpcontext)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId) };

    var userManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var signInManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    var httpContext = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
    httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
    httpcontext = httpContext;
    //controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;

    return userManager;
}
```

Comment: You have to setup the mock to behave as expected. However you should avoid coupling to implementation concern as they can have knock on effect when being mocked.

Comment: a bit of in-depth explanation please? I'm sorry i'm pretty new to this and still learning. I tried to do a mock setup but i'm not sure as to what am I supposed to mock as it doesnt let me do a mock of httpcontext..

Comment: If want to test controller action. I need to hide `UserManger` behind some abstraction to reduce coupling with asp.net indentity stuff.